# How to efficiently estimate quantile function of Gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-function, estimation

I have an application that analyzes datasets comprised mostly of samples from a Gamma distribution. Mixed in with the data are an unknown number ($>= 0$) of outlier samples (which are actually taken from a scaled noncentral chi-squared distribution with unknown centrality parameter) that are significantly larger in magnitude than the samples from the Gamma distribution. I would like to locate these values with as high of a detection probability as possible, under the constraint that the probability of falsely choosing one of the Gamma-distributed samples as an outlier is bounded by a specified probability $P_{f}$ (where $P_f$ is on the order of $10^{-8}$ to $10^{-12}$ or so).

The shape parameter $k$ of the Gamma distribution is known. I've developed the following method of approaching the problem:

- Fit a Gamma distribution to the data using a method that attempts to be robust to outliers:

  - Since the shape parameter is known, I just need the scale parameter $\theta$ in order to describe the distribution.
  - The mode of the distribution is equal to $(k-1)\theta$, so estimating the distribution's mode will provide a way to estimate $\theta$. I'm using the [half-sample range](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0505419) method to estimate the distribution's mode (i.e. the PDF's peak).
  - Given the mode estimate $m$, estimate the scale paramter as $\tilde \theta = \frac{m}{k-1}$.
- Given the desired false-detection probability $P_f$, calculate the threshold $x$ where $F_x(x) = 1 - P_f$, where $F_x(x)$ is the CDF of the fitted Gamma distribution.
- Declare all values in the sample greater than $x$ as outliers.

I'm looking for a computationally efficient way to estimate the appropriate threshold $x$. This is intended for a real-time processing application, and the method of directly inverting the Gamma distribution's CDF requires me to perform root-finding on special functions that are relatively expensive to compute. If there is a more efficient way to estimate (even approximately) the desired threshold in terms of the distribution parameters, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps unsurprisingly the [quantile function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) of the gamma distribution does not have a nice closed form.  I suspect that a lot of thought has been put into [R's implementation of its approximation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. R's implementation does give some good pointers; in addition, the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) has an open-source implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a quantile given a CDF can be done using binary interpolation, which will basically add a binary digit for each run of the CDF. This is possible because the CDF is inherently monotonic.

Your case sounds like one for a mixture distribution. I know this is an old question, but for new readers I suggest looking into [Tensorflow Probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability). With TFP you could define one main distribution with trainable parameters, one outlier distribution with trainable parameters and a mixture distribution with trainable weights. Usually you would then train the whole distribution on Maximal Likelihood, but you could also, for instance, first fit one distribution with one loss function and then the others with another loss function. (TFP currently does not calculate quantiles for mixtures or gammas out of the box, though.)