# Credible interval for gamma prior

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, confidence-interval

Let's cosnider $X_1, X_2,...,X_n \sim \textrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ i.i.d, and $\textrm{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$ as prior. Then posterior distribuion is $\textrm{Gamma}(\sum_i{X_i} + \alpha, n + \beta)$. We can deduce that bayesian estimator will be given as:
$$\hat T = \frac{\sum X_i + \alpha}{n + \beta}$$

I want to ask you for help in finidng $(1-c)$ credible interval for this problem. I've read that credible interval is such interval $(l, r)$ that satisfies:
$$\int_l^r  p(\theta \mid x) = 1 - c$$

But I'm not sure how to derive this with it. Do you know how this $l, r$ can be derived?

Comment: The usual approach to obtain an (approximate) credible interval is to sample from the posterior distribution and take the empirical quantiles. If you want an exact answer you can try to use the gamma CDF but it doesn't have a simple form

Comment: How exactly should I use gamma CDF? Could you please expand on that?

Comment: There is more than one credible interval but you could look for $l$ and $r$ such that $\int_0^l  p(\theta \mid x) = \frac{c}2$ and $\int_0^r  p(\theta \mid x) = 1-\frac{c}2$ which your favourite program will calculate for us (e.g. `qgamma` in R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find $r$ such that
$$\int_0^r p(\theta | x) = 1-c/2$$
and $l$ such that
$$\int_0^l p(\theta | x) = c/2$$
Then $(l,r)$ is a credible interval because
$$\int_l^r p(\theta | x) = 1-c$$

The value of $r$ satisfying the above is, by definition, the quantile function (inverse of the CDF) evaluated at $1-c/2$. The quantile function of the gamma distribution [does not have a convenient closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100791/how-to-efficiently-estimate-quantile-function-of-gamma-distribution) but can be approximated. In R, you can use `qgamma`.

You can also obtain a credible interval by sampling from the posterior distribution. I.e., take $10000$ samples from a $\text{Gamma}(X_i + \alpha, n + \beta)$ and look at the empirical quantiles. This is oftentimes the only available option when the models get more complicated...

Answer (score 1):

Hint, using a similar problem: Suppose the gamma prior distribution has shape parameter $4$ and rate parameter $1/3$ and that the sum of $50$ independent observations from $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$ is $256.$ The sample mean is $5.12.$

Then, by Bayes' Theorem, the posterior distribution is gamma with shape parameter $260$ and rate parameter $50.333,$ so that
a 95% Bayesian credible interval estimate for $\lambda$ is
approximately $(4.557,\, 5.812).$

In R, where `qgamma` is a gamma quantile function
(inverse CDF):

```
qgamma(c(.025,.975), 260,50.333) 
[1] 4.556734 5.812086
```

*Notes:* (1) R uses the shape/rate parameterization for
gamma distributions.

(2) The sampling method, suggested by
in the Answer by @philbo_baggins, gives one or two decimal places of accuracy with a sample
of 10,000:

```
set.seed(2022)
quantile(rgamma(10^4, 260, 50.333), c(.025,.975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
4.567375 5.810150 
quantile(rgamma(10^4, 260, 50.333), c(.025,.975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
4.557472 5.809427
```

(3) By contrast, one style of frequentist 95% confidence
interval gives $(4.531,\ 5.788).$

```
(256+2 + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(256+1))/50
[1] 4.531588 5.788412
```